# Unexpected behavior of file descriptor and/or I/O streams after running sqlcmd with -i option (read sql from file) in ksh creates infinite loop

Tags: io, ksh, file-descriptor, io-redirection, sqlcmd

**Is there a way to use `sqlcmd` with `-i input_file` option without creating an infinite loop in my ksh script?**

- The code reads lines from `$file` and parses it line-by-line to extract data and process other stuff.
- It uses file descriptors redirection to "read the `$file` from the `stdin`".

**Infinite loop code:**

```
exec 3<&0
exec 0<"${file}"
while read -r line || [[ -n ${line} ]]
do
    echo "${line}"
    sqlcmd -S svr -U usr -P pwd -i input_file >/dev/null 2>&1
done
exec 0<&3
exec 3<&-
echo "Script completed successfully!"
```

Output:

```
line 1 ...
line 1 ...
...
line 1 ...^C
```

**Workaround** (use *here document* instead of `-i input_file` option):

```
exec 3<&0
exec 0<"${file}"
while read -r line || [[ -n ${line} ]]
do
    echo "${line}"
    sqlcmd -S svr -U usr -P pwd <<-EOF
        -- SOME SQL CODE HERE
    EOF
    # here document lines are indented with tabs, not whitespaces.
done
exec 0<&3
exec 3<&-
echo "Script completed successfully!"
```

Output:

```
line 1 ...
line 2 ...
line 3 ...
Script completed successfully!
```

Even if there's a workaround for the issue I would like to know what's the reason for that behavior and how to use the `sqlcmd` tool without banning it's `-i input_file` option.

**Notes:**

- Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server.
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.7 (KornShell).

Comment: Seems like this should work, so please edit your Q with a sample `input_file.txt` with the minimal amount of code that reproduces the problem. Hopefully just `select SYSDATE()` (or similar). Good luck.

Comment: Hi @shellter , the issue is still there. I initially tried using an `INSERT` statement and also a `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM some_small_table` in the `input_file.txt`. I used the `SELECT SYSDATE()` instead but there's no change :( I'd be happy to try out some other ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but i don't have a way of duplicating your environment. Reviewing your Q, not clear why you need all the `exec 0<&3` etc stuff. Did you try the simpler form of `while read -r line ; do ..... done < $file` ? Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the code @shellter ...it is true that the simplest solution is the best :) I will look into `while read -r line ; do ..... done < $file `. Regarding the issue with the code above was that the `sqlcmd` was messing up with the **stdin**. Thanks for your useful contributions!

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Good luck and keep posting your well organized Qs (but don't make us guess about what is in `input_file` ;-) .

Comment: Sorry about that and thanks for pointing it out. I will keep it in mind for future posts :) Have a good week!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that `sqlcmd` was attempting to read from the **stdin** so appending `</dev/null` to the `sqlcmd` command fixed the problem. It is important to notice that I am redirecting the **stdin** from a *file* (`exec 0<"${file}"`).

#### Fix:

```
exec 3<&0
exec 0<"${file}"
while read -r line || [[ -n ${line} ]]
do
    echo "${line}"
    sqlcmd -S svr -U usr -P pwd -i input_file </dev/null
done
exec 0<&3
exec 3<&-
echo "Script completed successfully!"
```

Output:

```
line 1 ...
line 2 ...
line 3 ...
Script completed successfully!
```